# Formula to determine if a value is not an integer/is a decimal?

Tags: formula, cpq, steelbrick

I am trying to get a formula to determine if a price variable is calculated to be a decimal.

I haven't really been able to make any progress on this but I have to feel it's a simple function or set of functions I am unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the simplest way I know of determining this is by using `FLOOR()` and an equality check.

```
FLOOR(myField__c) = myField__c
```

The idea here is that `5` is treated as equal to `5.00`

This assumes your formula field is defined to be a checkbox type. A value of true means `myField__c` looks like an integer, and a value of false means `myField__c` looks like a decimal/float.

Of course, that only tells you if you could treat the current value of `myField__c` as an integer without losing any information. It isn't able to tell you much about how your field was defined (i.e. how many decimal places it can hold).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ISNUMBER` function to validate if the string is number or not.